# Restyling fine uploader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am attempting to use [fine uploader](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader) to handle some file uploading in a web application I have.  I would like to do some restyling but I am stuck on something.  In the [documentation on restyling](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/styling.html) they have the following line:

> The default drop area, button, and file list elements are also, **by
>   default**, contained in this option.

referring to a parent div with the class `qq-uploader`.

My question is if I can move certain pieces out of this div (in this case the file list elements).  The fact that they say "by default" seems to suggest it can be done, but I haven't seen any documentation on how to do it.  Has anyone done this before?  Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to do?

Comment: Move the file list outside of the div with the css class `qq-unloader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this before..but it was little styling..

i have to do is change little bit `qq.FileUploader` in these properties:

1. `template` which define the template for the whole uploader.
2. `fileTemplate` which define the template for one item in file list.

I was using older version(i think 2.1)..

my advice to you is to open the js file and look into it..it's good commented and 'll teach how this uploader is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new container to hold the file list, and place it wherever you want.  See the `listElement` option.  Probably no need to modify a template in this case.